# How to document a dict in Python?

Tags: python, dictionary, python-sphinx

I'm extracting data from xmls, and putting them into Elasticsearch. In an interim step, I have a dict that contains all the data I would like to put into Elasticsearch, and I would like to have these data docmented. The best would be to have this documentation together with the code, generated by Sphinx.

```
class MyCustomParser(Parser):

  def _get_data(self):
    # this is what matters
    data = {
        #: Shows if commitlog is required or not
        "has_commitlog": self._xml_helper.has_attribute_enabled('.//require_commitlog'),
```

What I would like to have is the dict's keys and the commented documentation above it. **The dict has around 50 lines, and I would like to extend it even further.**

I already searched around, but could not find any solution to this problem. My idea would be to change the dict to a custom dict-like object, document the object's attributes, and set them in the `_get_data` method above. What I don't like in this idea is its verbosity as instead of a slim dict definition I will end up with something like

```
MyCustomWhat(
  has_commitlog=self._xml_helper.has_attribute_enabled('.//require_commitlog'),
  ...
)
```

What would be your idea to document the keys of this dict inside the code?

Comment: Why arn't you satisfied with your 1st example, with one line of `comment`, one line with `'key':val`. It seems to be the clearest option to me

Comment: What about using a class/namespace instead of a dictionary?

Comment: You can attach a docstring to a class/instance attribute (which could be a dictionary), but there is no way to attach a docstring to each member of a dictionary and then generate useful output from that. In your case the dictionary isn't even a class attribute; it is an attribute of a method.